# Is it possible to write an Arduino program without the Arduino itself?

Tags: arduino

Hi I am curious to know is it possible to write an Arduino program without the Arduino breadboard itself? Can you emulate this some how instead of the hardware?

Comment: There is undoubtedly a way, but discussion of how would be considered "too broad" for Stack Overflow, and discussion of preexisting tools would be considered "out of scope"... This question would probably be better suited to an Arduino forum.

Answer (score 2):

[Found another post on here which was very helpful](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/78/4172)

> There are a whole slew of Arduino simulators out there, many free, and
>   some paid products as well.
>
> - The [CodeBlocks](http://arduinodev.com/codeblocks/) Arduino development environment includes a free Arduino simulator, still under development but functional.
> - [Simuino](https://code.google.com/p/simuino/) simulates the Arduino Uno and Mega pins - not a pretty-looking realistic simulator, but it works.
> - The Python based [Arduino Simulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/arduinosim/) is another option, that plays well with the official IDE
> - Virtronics [Simulator for Arduino](http://www.virtronics.com.au/Simulator-for-Arduino.html) looks promising, but I don't see why I would pay $14.99 for it, when I could buy one or more actual
>     Arduino clones for that price
>
> Many other Arduino simulators are out there if you search, and new
>   ones are being announced, even crowdfunded, all the time.